# Change screenshot block text and hit web api when user tries to take screenshot

Tags: android, android-intent, screenshot

I am preventing my app from taking screenshots. For this, I am using   `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

When the user wants to take the screenshot, I am getting message `"Couldn't save the screenshot, Stroage may be in use"`. I want to customize this message as per my requirement. Also when user tries to take the screenshot I want to hit the web api.

I am using below code but with no success

```
public void detectScreenShotService(final Activity activity){

        final Handler h = new Handler();
        final int delay = 3000; //milliseconds
        final ActivityManager am=(ActivityManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rs=am.getRunningServices(200);

                for(ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo ar:rs){
                    if(ar.process.equals("com.android.systemui:screenshot")){
                        Log.e("tag", "Screenshot captured!!");
                    }
                }
                h.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line of code before `setContentView` in all activities

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: I am doing same, How can I change toast message that says "Cant take screenshot".

Comment: @theLazyFinder I think it cant be changed I tried of searching on the same.

Comment: If you overcome from that please let me know